# How can I Register and Store Data in Firebase Database - Android Studio | Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a registration system in my project where users can create an account. But how can I put their records in Firebase Realtime Database?

By hitting the register button, the account is created and I also want the records to store in the firebase database.

```
package com.example.sampleapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText regFullName, regEmail, regPass, confPass;
    Button regBtn, gotoLogin;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        regFullName = findViewById(R.id.regFullName);
        regEmail = findViewById(R.id.regEmail);
        regPass = findViewById(R.id.regPass);
        confPass = findViewById(R.id.confPass);
        regBtn = findViewById(R.id.regBtn);
        gotoLogin = findViewById(R.id.gotoLogin);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        //Back to Login Page
        gotoLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Code for opening new Classes
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        //Register Button
        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Extracting Data from the forms
                String FullName = regFullName.getText().toString();
                String Email = regEmail.getText().toString();
                String Password = regPass.getText().toString();
                String ConfirmPass = confPass.getText().toString();


                if (FullName.isEmpty()){
                    regFullName.setError("Full Name is Required.");
                    return;
                }
                if (Email.isEmpty()){
                    regEmail.setError("Email is Required.");
                    return;
                }
                if (Password.isEmpty()){
                    regPass.setError("Password is Required.");
                    return;
                }
                if (ConfirmPass.isEmpty()){
                    confPass.setError("Confirm Your Password.");
                    return;
                }

                //Confirming if the Password is not correct
                if (!Password.equals(ConfirmPass)){
                    confPass.setError("Password Do Not Match.");
                    return;
                }


                //Registering the user
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Data Validated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        //Send user to next page
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I tried doing the methods in youtube videos but it won't work. I am able to create an account but the records are not inserting to the database

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to create an account but the records are not inserted into the database.

When you call [FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) it:

> Tries to create a new user account with the given email address and password. If successful, it also signs the user into the app.

But this operation doesn't automatically insert user data into the database. If you need that, you have to do it yourself. So you can solve that in two ways, you either use the following lines of code on the client when the authentication is successful:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("uid", uid);
//Add other user data
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("users");
usersRef.child(uid).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

Or you can [trigger a function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) when the authentication is successful.

Comment: Hey Marc. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?